# Angular - Combine two select ng-models values into one

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am new to Angular so all help is appreciated.  I have two select dropdowns that I need to combine into one value and assigned to cusPro.height.  This was working like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="height" ng-model="cusPro.height">
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
etc...
```

But I want to do this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="height_ft" ng-model="feet">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    etc...
<select class="form-control" name="height_in" ng-model="inches">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    etc...
```

I tried putting `cusPro.height = feet + '\' ' + inches + '\"';` and got:

> referenceError: cusPro is not defined

Comment: You might consider showing your ng model code...

Comment: Where did you try setting `cusPro.height`? If it's inside your controller, you may have forgotten to assign `this` to a variable named `cusPro`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map one "model" to two fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618182/how-to-map-one-model-to-two-fields)

Answer (score 0):

First off, Angular overrides the `select` directive with its own implementation that does not require multiple `option` tags. Please read up on how that works [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Then your HTML will look something like this:

```
<select ng-model="cusPro.feet" ng-options="feetLength for feetLength in feetLengths">
<select ng-model="cusPro.inches" ng-options="inchesLength for inchesLengthin inchesLengths">

You selected: {{cusPro.feet}} feet, {{cusPro.inches}} inches
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Controller`:

```
$scope.feet = []; // Your data
$scope.inches = []; // Your data

// Merge data
$scope.displayedData = $scope.fee.concat($scope.inches);
```

In your `view`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="height_ft" ng-model="displayedData">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
```